# CURL got Could not resolve host: my subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, dns

I'm using wordpress and I installed [jwt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/).

My WordPress is installed on sub domain and I want to call jwt from the main domain.

when I call this URL from postman:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
```

it returns a response but when I call this URL from inside my main domain:

```
$url = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token';


$data = array(
    'username' => '***',
    'password' => '***'
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);



die("dd".$result.$error_msg);
```

it returns:

```
ddCould not resolve host: subdomain.domain.com
```

My DNS config:

```
A @ myip
CNAME www maindomain
A subdomain myip
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Are the main domain and subdomain set up on the same server? Or are they on two different servers?

Comment: @maiorano84 both of them are on the same server.

Comment: So there's a few things at play that can be happening here. If your subdomain was set up recently, it's possible that you might have DNS caching on your network that could be failing to retrieve the new record. The other possibility is that DNS hasn't fully propagated through the internet yet, and your home network is seeing the change before your server can. Since both sites are on the same server, try adding an `/etc/hosts` entry to point the subdomain locally for now. See if that helps.